# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Unable to detect changed language in BlackBerry 7

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-webworks

The API method `WL.App.getDeviceLanguage()` doesn't get "updated" after the language on the device is changed.

Consider an application with the following code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert(WL.App.getDeviceLanguage());
}, 2*1000);
```

If the device is set to English, the application will alert `en` correctly. However, if you close/pause the application, change the language and then go back into the app, it will still alert `en`. To get the language to be reported as the changed language, *the battery has to be removed for a complete reboot of the device*.

Any suggestions? Seems like a Worklight bug to me. I'm using Worklight version 6.

I'll also note that `navigator.language` produces the same result, and `blackberry.system.language` returns `undefined` on **BB7**.

Comment: What is the purpose of the setInterval?

Comment: So the alert will keep popping up after coming back into the application after changing the language. There are many ways this could've been done, with a button etc., or ideally on the 'resume' event, but that doesn't work in BB7 either but that issue is not really relevant here.

Comment: is this question resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `WL.App.getDeviceLocale()` instead.

Also, Worklight 6.0.0.x uses Cordova 2.6. Try, then, to use the [Cordova Globalization API set](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization). Specifically, the [`getPreferredLanguage`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getPreferredLanguage) method.

Finally, there is the [`System` object](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/gold/blackberry.system.html) in the WebWorks API. See the following Learning sample from BlackBerry:

- [Recognizing System Language Changes Sample that demonstrates how to work with device region and language changes (link to GitHub)](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Localization) (might be BB10 specific, try)

I am also told that for BB7 the following extension is required:

- https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/Smartphone/Locale